# How to use VLOOKUP and get details from other sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have following sheet available in my workbook

```
test,input,model,cm,mm,output
```

I would like to get input from input sheet.

1. add the column before the test column which is "mark" and vlookup based on house(,) to sheet "CM" house to mark.
2. I need to get "dear" detail from  "CM" based house
3. I need to get "son" detail from  "MM" based house
4. I need to add column between brother and son. Which has named as mark and vlook based on son and get from model sheet.

Input

```
test    mail    god house   dear    moon    son brother loosee  man boy girl    test
dd  d   d   sd  dfd 123 dfd ad  d   df  sd  d   d


model                                               
pop mark                                            
123 jklm                                            
CM                                              
house   dear    mark                                        
sd  dfd love                                        
MM                                              

moon    son                                         
123 dfd
```

I am trying to write the following code to get all details and get output. but I am getting failed pls guide me to solve it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim ws1LR As Long, ws2LR As Long

    Set ws1 = Sheets("input")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("output")

    ws1LR = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws2LR = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    i = 2
    k = ws2LR
    Do Until i = ws1LR
        With ws1
            .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 18)).Copy
        End With

        With ws2
            .Cells(k, 1).PasteSpecial
            .Cells(k, 1).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        End With

        k = k + 2
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: couldn't understand your exact goal. please give a real example of starting and final sheets

Comment: A good first step, turn on the macro recorder and perform the steps manually.  That will get you much of what you need to automate the task in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve your goals is:

```
Sub prueba()


    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1

    Dim point2 As String
    Dim point3 As String

    Dim query As String

    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\prueba.xlsx;" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    query = "Select cm.dear FROM [input$] as i inner join [cm$] as cm on i.house = cm.house where test is not null"

    objRecordset.Open query, _
        objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    'since query returns one row so:

    point2 = objRecordset.Fields.Item("dear") '<---- returns "dfd"

    objRecordset.Close

    query = "Select mm.moon FROM [input$] as i inner join [mm$] as mm on i.house = mm.house where test is not null"

    'following line cant return any value because there is not any house field on mm table
    objRecordset.Open query, _
        objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    point3 = objRecordset.Fields.Item("moon")


End Sub
```

All you should to know about this code, is how to write the proper query.

Pay attention to query variable, it's like a sql query, you can join several tables and look for a value where these two values in two fields (columns) are equal. That's because you cant run the second query, because there is not a field called house in mm table (accordingly to your example).