# Comparing two columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am supposed to download a worksheet (call it the first workbook) that contains customer Ids (about 100). We have a different workbook (workbook2) that contains all of the customer Ids and the names of those customers. I would like to translate those customer Ids from workbook1 into their prospective names based on the second workbook. I think I have a pretty decent foundation so far but I have hit a wall with debugging. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
Option Explicit

Sub getcompanyname()

Dim wsll As Worksheet
Dim wsd As Workbook

Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range

Dim lastRow2 As Integer
lastRow2 = Workbooks("MatchWerks Customer Quick Reference.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set wsd = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Dylan Hoffman\Documents\SugarSync Shared Folders\Support\Customer Support\MatchWerks Customer Quick Reference.xlsx")
Set wsll = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("customtableitem_customtable_mbs")

For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("customtableitem_customtable_mbs").Columns("C1:C" & lastRow).Cells

    For Each d In Workbooks("MatchWerks Customer Quick Reference.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A3:A" & lastRow2).Cells
    If c = d Then
    c = d.Offset(0, 1)
    End If
    Next d
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to fetch data with a query. You should see a sample for this in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617903/how-to-use-vlookup-and-get-details-from-other-sheet-using-vba/36213294#36213294)

Comment: Wow I didn't know you could use sql in Excel! so what you are saying is i should do an inner join between the two workbooks?

Comment: That sample works for tables in one workbook (one database for your purpose). I think you could copy the target worksheet, using vba, into workbook(database) source and query like I explained in the other post.

Comment: Okay ill mess around with that sample you provided, thanks for you input